# Assign more importance to recent records during training

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, weights, weighted-data

I have a large dataset with information from the last year. I have to build a classification model in order to predict if a customer will buy a product or not (binary classification). Since in the last months (let's say 3-4) I know that the advertising of the company is changed a bit, I want to put more emphasis on the newer records.

I know that it is possible to specify the `sample_weights` parameter in most of the classification algorithms, but I don't know **how to properly build these weights.** Basically, I have **the date in which the customers have (or have not) bought the product**, but I want to understand if there is a specific way to build the weights starting from this information.

In addition, I would also know if someone knows some references or applications for this application (time-related weights).

Thank you!